# Intent.resolveActivity(...) or PackageManager.resolveActivity(...) ? When to use what?

Tags: android, android-intent

So this is a function in my android project,

```
private fun openCamAndTakePic() {
        val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        
// activity!!.packageManager.resolveActivity(takePictureIntent,
//                                           PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
//                                           ).also {
//                              (or)

   takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity!!.packageManager).also{

            val photoFile = createPhotoFile()

            photoURI = createURIForFile(photoFile)

            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoURI)

            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,CAMERA_PHOTO_REQUEST)

        }
    }
```

Both work for me. 
So I'm confused as to which one to use (or) rather which one is meant for this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a possibility that the activity was not found to handle the Intent. Some devices sometimes failed to support the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` on `Intent`. If you try starting an activity, and there is no match, you will get an `ActivityNotFoundException`, so this check is trying to avoid such an exception.